# Where to find a rosbag

Tags: rosbag, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I know I've seen that question somewhere but I can't seem to find it again. I would like to know if there is somewhere I can download rosbags. Like a database of rosbag available for free. It could be a very handy thing. Like for now I'm stuck without a camera and I'm searching for a rosbag of an Xtion looking at an object. I'm pretty someone else already have done this.

If there isn't, does someone have rosbag of this type I could possibly use ?

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194132/where-to-find-a-rosbag./) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many computer vision research labs working on ROS/robotics will have what you need.

First few links from a quick Google search:

[http://webdiis.unizar.es/~glopez/dataset](http://webdiis.unizar.es/%7Eglopez/dataset)

http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/download/objecttracking.html

http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/download

You are responsible for following their licensing, referencing and privacy requirements.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1